# Vuex action "not a function" inside Nuxt fetch

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I have just introduced error handling to one of my Nuxt pages and apparently the action mapped and called inside `fetch` raises a *not a function* error. If the `try`/`catch` block isn't there it works as expected and there's no error at all.

Here is my component stripped to the essential parts:

```js
export default {
  name: 'ViewArticle',
  async fetch ({ error }) {
    try {
      await this.fetchArticle({ articleSlug: this.articleSlug })
    } catch (err) {
      error({ statusCode: 404, message: 'May the force be with you' })
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      article: 'article/single'
    }),
    articleSlug () {
      return this.$route.params.articleSlug
    }
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions({
      fetchArticle: 'article/fetchOne'
    })
  }
}
```

I am assuming that somehow mapActions only gets executed later in the spiel, but can't figure out how to prevent the error. This way, basically every time I load the page it gets immediately redirected to the error page.

The error message I'm getting is the following. Obviously `fetchArticle` *is* a function, and unless it's inside the `try`/`catch` block, it works as expected.

```
this.fetchArticle is not a function                                                                                                               03:30:51

  at Object.fetch (52.js:32:18)
  at server.js:2881:39
  at Array.map (<anonymous>)
  at module.exports../.nuxt/server.js.__webpack_exports__.default (server.js:2864:51)
```

Comment: What is the exact error message, please

Comment: @Phil just updated my question with it

Comment: what version of Nuxt you are using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fetch provides the `context` as argument.

```
fetch(context)
```

Inside the context we can find our store. Here you can take a look what context contains: https://nuxtjs.org/api/context

```
fetch(context) {
   let store = context.store;
}
```

People like to destructure it

```
fetch({ store }) {}
```

Your code should look like this:

```
  async fetch ({ error, store }) {
    try {
      await store.dispatch('article/fetchOne', { articleSlug: this.articleSlug })
    } catch (err) {
      error({ statusCode: 404, message: 'May the force be with you' })
    }
  },
```

Fetch gets executed on the server side, thats why you get `is not an function` error. Its undefined

> ... fetch is called on server-side...

Answer (score 0):

Use `async fetch({store})`

```
  async fetch ({ error, store }) {
    try {
      await store.dispatch( 'article/fetchOne' , { articleSlug: this.articleSlug })
    } catch (err) {
      error({ statusCode: 404, message: 'May the force be with you' })
  }
```